# How can we write a function to take the file name and create the data frame in pandas without using built-ins?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to write a function that takes the CSV file's name and then create its pandas data frame printed?
I write this too simple code, but it does not work:

```
def ols_reg(filename):
    '''      '''
    df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")     #assumption: the directory of both files is same  
    print(df)
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What exactly are you trying to do? Pass the name of a file to a function, that then does some operation on that file?

Comment: `but it does not work:` - what does that mean? Can you give a little more detail? How is it deficient? How does its result differ from your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

If you just throw "filename" into the string, it doesn't read it as a variable. Introduce it as an f-string by throwing 'f' in front of the string and surrounding your variable in brackets.

```
def ols_reg(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(f"{filename}.csv")     #assumption: the directory of both files is same  
    print(df)
```